# Save form data to text with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a landing page with an email signup form. I need to save the email addresses to a `.txt` file.

I already have a php script that emails me each time a user enters data into the form. I would like to add on to that script to save the same data to a `.txt` file. I do not know enough about php to do this and got an error each time I tried.

Here is the php file:

```
<?php

/* Save file commands */




/* Subject and Email variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Real Family Trips Contest';
    $webmaster = 'my-email@domain.com';


/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $emailField = $_POST['emailaddy'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email address: $emailField <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $emailField\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail ($webmaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
    header('Location: http://realfamilytrips.com/share-itineraries');
exit();
?>
```

And here is the form:

```
<form action="/signup.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="emailaddy" value="Enter your email address" title="Enter your email address" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="send" />
</form>
```

I am unsure if I need a new `.php` file for this, or if it can be done with the one I currently have. If I have to create a new file, what goes in the form `action= area?` Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be running the script multiple times, wanting to append the email addresses.  So you need special options to [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) or fwrite

```
file_put_contents("emails.txt", $emailField . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

This will append to the end of the file.  Also, adding the "\n" to the end of the $emailField from your script will have email addresses one per line.

Comment: Great thanks! Now my follow up question is this- If I have my form action= set to a mailchimp url can I somehow add a second action to the same form and trigger the PHP code? And this line you gave me, is it ok to put it where I already have it commented out? Meaning, is it ok to go at the top of the php code I have currently? Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: You can add a bit of javascript code that runs when the form is submitted, and that can call the php script on your server using an AJAX call, then the form can continue on and submit to mailchimp when that AJAX call completes. See [jQuery submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [jQuery get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) which is about the simplest interface to do an AJAX call.  Best of all, you can leave the mailchimp HTML form unmodified and still accomplish what you want.

Comment: Oh, and the second part to your comment, just put that php code after the $emailField variable is defined.  You need to do it before you output headers and exit.  I'd suggest putting it in right before the $body = <<<EOD line

Answer (score 0):

```
$myFile = "email.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $body);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents)

You can use that to store whatever you want in a text based file.

An example of it in use for your case would be something like:

```
$filename = 'email_list.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, $body, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Your answer and the one above are very similar so I will try them both. Thanks a lot. I do have a follow up question. If I have my form action= set to a mailchimp url, how can I add a second action to the same form and trigger the PHP code? And can I add this code you provided to the top of my existing php? I have a place commented out for it, but I don't know if there is an order or hierarchy to these things. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $output_file = 'myTextFile.txt';
    $textFileData = 'insert data here';
    file_put_contents($output_file, $textFileData);
?>
```

https://www.php.net/file_put_contents